# Eclipse Launch Group - How does Launch Mode work?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, spring-tool-suite

I am working with STS based on Eclipse

About `Run Configurations`

I have some `Maven` configurations for `Main` executions defined through the `Maven Build` section. I need execute some of them together, for this goal I am working with the `Launch Group` section as follows:

[image]

From above I added three *configurations* to run together.

When I added each one, or even if I need update/edit each one - exists the following (observe the bottom part):

[image]

From above I did do some experiments about the `Post launch action` options and I understand clearly how works each one. Until here all is fine.

The situation is about the `Launch mode` options as follows:

[image]

From above I understand `run` option, it is the common or simplest execution.

But I am not able to figure out - what do or how work the rest of the options:

- Inherit
- Profile
- Database Debug (Not sure if this option/item appears because I have the `Dbeaver` plugin installed)

**Question**: therefore how `Inherit`, `Profile` and `Database Debug` work? (Mostly the two first). If some scenarios or situations can be shared about when to use each one, it is appreciate to have a better perspective.

BTW if I choice `Profile`, appears the following error message (see blue square), as follows, so not sure when would be used (it is confuse)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ***launch mode*** must be supported by the type of the launch configuration to be able to **select it without an error**.

**Maven** launch configurations support the launch mode ***Run* only**.

For launch configurations that supports the launch mode *Run* and *Debug* (like e.g. *Java Application* launch configurations), also ***Inherit*** can be chosen. *Inherit* means the **launch mode of the launch group**. Use the drop-down of the *Debug* button in the main toolbar to launch the launch group in *Debug* mode or the drop-down of the *Run* button to launch the launch group in *Run* mode. Alternatively, a launch group can be executed via the menu *Run > Run Configurations...* respectively *Run > Debug Configurations...* in the *Run* respectively *Debug* mode.

Launch groups exist [since Eclipse Oxygen (4.7)](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.7/platform.php#launch-groups). This short [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y0-cO9wZj6w&t=20s) shows them in action. *Run* and *Debug* are the basic launch modes. All others with the exception of *Inherit* are contributed by additional plug-ins. For example, the *Profile* launch mode comes with [Eclipse EclEmma](https://www.eclemma.org/) for Java code coverage which is built-in in all Java IDE packages.

The dialog should not offer the option to choose a not supported mode. Maybe this is because plug-ins can add additional launch modes (in your case *Database Debug*) or maybe because nobody has implemented it yet (Eclipse is open source and contributions like this are welcome).

Comment: Can you please expand the `Inherit` scenario? What is inherited? ...

Comment: @ManuelJordan I have edited the answer. _Inherit_ means the mode of the launch group, which can be launched either in *Debug* or in *Run* mode.

Comment: @ManuelJordan _Profile_ is from [EclEmma](https://www.eclemma.org/) for Java code coverage which works in _Java Application_, _JUnit_, _Eclipse Application_, etc. launch configurations but not in a _Maven_ launch configuration (see my extended answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to run launch groups in coverage mode but have not been able to make it work. This seems to be a limitation in Eclipse. It would be useful to run a group of unit tests in coverage mode.